# How can I implement a general nonlinear piece-wise define function as objective in Gurobi?

Tags: python, optimization, gurobi

I have a piece-wise function to be used as the objective function in Gurobi (alpha_beta):

```
import gurobipy as gp
m = gp.Model()
lb = 0.1
ub = 0.6
x1 = m.addVar(vtype=gp.GRB.CONTINUOUS, lb=lb, ub=ub)
x2 = m.addVar(vtype=gp.GRB.CONTINUOUS, lb=lb, ub=ub)
m.addConstr(x1+x2, gp.GRB.EQUAL, 1, "cons")
def alpha_beta(x):
    a = 0.0019727939
    b = 0.0078887
    Lmin, Lnom, Lmax = 0.8035, 2.3811, 3.084
    if x < Lnom:
        return a * ((x - Lnom)**2) + 0.006226
    else:
        return b * ((x - Lnom)**2) + 0.006226
```

Here is the objective function I need:

```
Ldf = [5.2]
L10 = 2.2
L20 = 2.2
def obj():
    val = ((alpha_beta(x1*Ldf[0]))\
           +alpha_beta(x2*Ldf[0]))*44+\
    3600*(x1*Ldf[0]-L10)**2 + 3600*(x2*Ldf[0]-L20)**2
    return val
m.setObjective(obj(), GRB.MINIMIZE)
```

Defining the function in this way is not working, how can I implement this objective function in Gurobi?
Thank you very much!

Comment: Apologies for my prior answer - I misread the problem as piecewise linear, not piecewise quadratic.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is an optimization modeling question that belongs on or.stackexchange.com.